# Is it possible to perform a disabling attack that does not cause permanent damage?

Tags: self-defense

I've developed myself into Karate, Kung-fu (Hung gar and Shaolin) and Krav-maga.

That being said - I'm looking for the development of natural effective movements to make a self-defense action without causing injuries to the opponent. I know that it is a difficult call but, could one strikes in such a way that will just cause momentary (1-5 min) pain or faint in order to just stop the fight?

How confident can I be that by hitting the KO head spots, the opponent will not have problems afterwards?

This is not a duplication of [Looking for a martial art to do, self defense without causing pain?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/looking-for-a-martial-art-to-do-self-defense-without-causing-pain). They are talking about avoiding to cause pain. This is not what I'm asking here: *I want to know means that may or not cause pain without sending the opponent to the hospital.*

Comment: Please take a look at 
 [Looking for a martial art to do, self defense without causing pain?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/looking-for-a-martial-art-to-do-self-defense-without-causing-pain) - your question seems like a likely duplicate.

Comment: Oh. Thank you @Bankuei . Sorry for that! Will take a look now.

Comment: No worries!  If you decide you have further questions, either revise your question here or create a new one.

Comment: Sorry @Bankuei ...Not a duplication at all. They are talking about avoiding to cause pain. This is not what I'm asking here. I want to now means that may or not cause pain without sending the opponent to the hospital.

Comment: You should take [the tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how we work. I edited your question to make it not asking for a list of things (off topic & bad) and collapsed some of the comments into the question. Also, it is bad to accept an answer too early (within 24 hours?) since that might discourage others to write their (potentially better) answer.

Comment: Thank you @Sardathrion. I will do the tour. Sorry for the bad practice.

Comment: No worries. We all started out and made those same mistakes… I know I did!☺

Comment: I'm sure your coaches will have methods of sparring for you to minimize damage. We wear 16oz gloves for sparring, and go hard to the body, light to the head.

Comment: I've always found that the only effective way to dominate an opponent without injury is to possess a massively higher level of skill. Otherwise your attacks will by necessity either require damage or be ineffective.

Comment: Are you looking to develop an approach to self-defense which does not cause injury to your opponent, or are you wondering how confident you can be that the "KO head spots" don't cause injuries?  I would have to approach the two questions differently.  One is a discussion of philosophies and schools.  The other starts from assuming KOs are the correct solution for incapacitation and asks how bad the side effects are.

Comment: Hey @CortAmmon! I know that KO hits can cause injuries. The question is simple: With my quoted knowledge, is there a way to cause 1 to 5 minutes incapacitation without side effects? Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guaranteed technique to stop the fight and ensure the safety of everyone involved.  (Well, running away has a high success rate, provided you are in a place where you can run and are more fit than the assailant).

If you knock someone out, you're giving them a concussion. [Concussions are a form of brain damage](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/any-conditioning-exercise-that-can-prevent-concussion-caused-by-a-punch-or-kick/6710#6710) and you can never be sure how severe the actual concussion will be.  You cannot be confident at all.

If you apply a blood choke to cause someone to lose consciousness, they will be incapacitated from a few seconds up to a few minutes - but it's hard to gauge how fast they'll come back.  These tend to have higher reliability in terms of quick put-down with less damage, BUT they're also hard to get to in a fight - you have to fight to get into a position to apply them, typically.  Many security or police forces are also forbidden from using blood chokes due to the fact extended holds cause permanent brain damage from oxygen deprivation.

All other forms of pain compliance are a gamble and usually the pain disappears right away or a few moments after the technique is no longer applied.  Adrenaline, alcohol, or drugs might make a person not feel the pain in which case they can still fight back with whatever means they have available.  For people who do feel the pain, you might be able to completely immobilize or control them depending on your training.

However, most pain compliance holds require lots of skill to "jump into" against an attacking opponent.  You usually have to fight for position before you can get to a good option, and that may involve striking for distraction... which again leads us back to space for injury and concussion.  After you get a pain compliance hold, if the person doesn't feel pain or is very aggressive, you might end up breaking one of their joints or tearing tendons, even without trying.

Martial arts as an entire endeavor across the world exist simply because no one has come up with "the few easy ways to win most/all of the time and not hurt people".

Comment: Thank you so much @Bankuei ! I'm striving to find a way of no infliction, but like you've explained, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: @Methark: To some degree, it's the same problem as the police face with their "non-lethal" weapons being closer to "much-less-lethal". Tear gas can disable. It can also asphyxiate (or ignite). Stun guns and tasers can cause hearts to stop. Bean bag rounds and rubber bullets break bones and crush tracheas. If you'll pardon the slight play on words, there is no magic bullet.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Yes. I've got to this enclosure here. Just for the record, there is a laser being developed right now with no side-effects - the problem is the weight and size of the cannon. :)